# Getting flask backend information into my webpage

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have this Python/flask code

```
@app.route('/prompt', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def prompt():
    global prompt
    prompt = request.form['prompt'] #parse received content to variable
    print(chatbot.chat(prompt))
    return chatbot.chat(prompt)
```

and this async function

```
async function yourFunction() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        const yourCallback = () => {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            const receivedData = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(receivedData);
          } else {
            // handle errors here
            console.log("an error occurred");
          }
        };
        // just open() now
        xhr.open("GET", "/prompt");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = yourCallback;
        xhr.send();
      }
```

Its called through this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitButton").click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", true);
          $.ajax({
            data: { prompt: document.getElementById("promptArea").value },
            type: "POST",
            url: "/prompt", //post grabbed text to flask endpoint for saving role
            success: function (data) {
              console.log("Sent Successfully");
              yourFunction();
            },
            error: function (e) {
              console.log("Submission failed...");
            },
          });
        });
      });
```

However, the python code works, while this javascript gives me a 400 error? I dont really understand why, what is behind this happening?